ACCESS2007 UPDATE a memo field with the content of an OLE fields with text embedded as word.document VBA
Good morning to everybody. I'm working around this matter without solution. I'm looking for VBA code for to copy the content of an OLE object (pre_testo) [table DB_PREV] embedded as word.document to a memo field (pre_report) [same table]. At the moment I tried several code unsuccesfully. Thank you in advance for any kind of suggestions.

Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code-writing service. We can help with problems in your code, but we don't do your work for you. See [ask].

Finally this code work well but the content loose format. I'm working around the matter and I will share results. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Dim oleObj As Object 
Dim memoContent As String 
Set oleObj = Me.pre_testo 'embedded as Word.Document
oleObj.Activate
memoContent = oleObj.Object.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Text
Me.pre_report.Value = memoContent 'pre_report field as memo RTF
Forms![PREWIN].Requery
DoCmd.OpenReport "PREVENTIVI", acViewPreview, , "ID =" & Me!ID 


Dim oleObj As Object
Dim memoContent As String
Dim memoRep As String
Me!pre_report.Value = ""
Set oleObj = Me.pre_testo
oleObj.Activate
memoContent = oleObj.Object.Application.ActiveDocument.Content.Text
'this row garanty the right format
memoContent = Replace(memoContent, Chr(13), Chr(11))
Me!pre_report.Value = memoContent
DoCmd.OpenReport "PREVENTIVI", acViewPreview, , "ID =" & Me!ID

End Sub
